# How do I get all view fields in a preprocess hook?

Tags: views, 8

In a view, I have an image field. I would like to get all the fields and process the image field.

```
function template_preprocess_views_view(array &$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
}
```

How can I get those fields?

Answer (score 1):

If your use case allows for this, I would use rendered content (maybe a new view mode if the others are used somewhere else) in the view and do all the preprocessing on the node level (if needed).
Usually, twig is enough to properly format the output of the node.